# Im looking to set a variable from another table in Marketing Cloud but I cant get the statement to work

Tags: marketing-cloud

Im looking to return the value based on a subscriber from another DE in Marketing Cloud and use it as a variable in m email. I tried setting it in the following way but I'm now confused what should be used to complete the statement?

IT should be based on row value from the uniquecode column from the `TestDE123`

the value that matches them is the PersonID column & value which is in both tables.

```ampscript
%%[ var = @uniquecode 
set @uniquecode = Lookup("TestDE123","uniquecode",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the quick answer is:

```ampscript
%%[
  set @personID = AttributeValue("PersonID")
  set @uniquecode = Lookup("TestDE123","uniquecode","PersonID",@personID)
]%%
```

But the longer answer is:

First, the way you are trying to establish the variable is wrong and will likely cause a syntax error. If you were to want to establish variables prior to setting them, you would do it like this `var @uniquecode` without the equal sign. I do not do this personally as I see little real benefit in it and it can bloat your code. Others find value in it and technically it is considered best practice officially.

Second, lets take a look at the **[LookUp](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/)** function. From the documentation you will see that there are 4 properties required with the ability to add more name/value pairs afterwards.

These properties are:

1. Name of the Data Extension to look up the info from
2. Name of the field from that Data Extension you want to return the value from
3. Name of the field you want to use for a match for the lookup
4. Value of the named field you want to match on
   5+ - repeates of 3 and 4 to help make your filter more accurate.

As a note, 3 and 4 will only ever be 'equal to' you will not be able to use any other simple operators. This is basically matching the values between two foreign keys (two fields in two data tables that can match values to form a relationship between the tables to help share data.)

So the last 2 properties were what you were missing in your function, but by the context in the question, you mentioned 'PersonID' is the foreign key, so by just using that information, I was able to build out the above to help complete your Lookup function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply just making sure I can use this again in the future:
PersonID - Is this the name of the column that is in common between the two data extensions - so I can just take the name as it is?
The look up value will just return the first row or it will return any row. I may have duplicate rows but just want the first one.

Comment: @user48743 - So PersonID in the lookup is the name of the column in the target DE that you want to match values on. Then the 4th parameter is the value to search. Lookup will then find the first match of value to value and then return the value in the 2nd parameter (in this case "uniquecode") to fill the variable you set. If there is no match, then it will return null/empty to the variable. Does this help?